# ¿como insertar datos en array php, mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Necesito insertar multiples registros en una tabla de mysql, desde otra tabla, pero solo se inserta el primer registro de la tabla 
mi codigo es el siguiente

```
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Conectado a la base de datos correctamente";
//Obtener checadas desde el biometrico
$asistencia = $zk->getAttendance();
foreach($asistencia as $key=>$valor) {
  $id = $valor[1];
  foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM usuariosBiometrico WHERE id=".$id) as $dato) {
    $chofer = $dato['usuario'];
  }
  $fecha = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( $valor[3] ) );
  $hora = date( "H:i:s", strtotime( $valor[3] ) );
  $datosInsertar = array(
    'chofer' => $chofer,
    'fecha' => $fecha,
    'hora' => $hora
  );
  echo json_encode($datosInsertar);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO checadas (chofer, fecha, hora) VALUES ('".implode("', '", $datosInsertar)."')";
}

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "Registros insertados correctamente";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

en el JSON si se muestran todos los registros pero al insertarlos en la base de datos solo se inserta un registro
¿que puedo hacer para que se inserten todos los registros en los campos que corresponden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas haciendo la incersion fuera del bucle.  Tienes que hacerlo despues de cada iteracion asi:

```
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Conectado a la base de datos correctamente";
//Obtener checadas desde el biometrico
$asistencia = $zk->getAttendance();
foreach($asistencia as $key=>$valor) {
  $id = $valor[1];
  foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM usuariosBiometrico WHERE id=".$id) as $dato) {
    $chofer = $dato['usuario'];
  }
  $fecha = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( $valor[3] ) );
  $hora = date( "H:i:s", strtotime( $valor[3] ) );
  $datosInsertar = array(
    'chofer' => $chofer,
    'fecha' => $fecha,
    'hora' => $hora
  );
  echo json_encode($datosInsertar);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO checadas (chofer, fecha, hora) VALUES ('".implode("', '", $datosInsertar)."')";
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "Registros insertados correctamente";
  } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```